# ActiveMQ 5.15.9 - limiting storage to 100 GB when producerFlowControl is false and Systemusage is not set

Tags: activemq-classic

I'm experiencing a weird issue with ActiveMQ 5.19.x embedded in Camel 2.25.0 . It is limiting the storage to 100 GB without a reason. Systemusage is not set. Previously we had a limit there but I removed later on.

I checked and disk space was available.

```
ActiveMQ VMTransport: vm://oooo-broker#809-1 |  |  | o.a.activemq.broker.region.Queue | Usage(Main:store:queue://.....:store) percentUsage=99%, usage=107374272210, limit=107374182400, percentUsageMinDelta=1%;Parent:Usage(Main:store) percentUsage=100%, usage=107374272210, limit=107374182400, percentUsageMinDelta=1%: Persistent store is Full, 100% of 107374182400. Stopping producer (ID:int1.prima.pricefx.net-33479-1632477163918-10:27:5:1) to prevent flooding queue://oooo. See http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html for more info (blocking for: 9s)
```

My configuration is follows:

```xml
<amq:broker id="broker" brokerName="im-oooo-broker" useShutdownHook="false" useJmx="true"
              persistent="true" dataDirectory="${data.directory}/activemq-data"
              xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core">
    <amq:transportConnectors>
      <!-- vm transport for intra-jvm communication -->
      <amq:transportConnector name="vm" uri="vm://oooo-broker"/>
    </amq:transportConnectors>
    <!-- queues -->
    <amq:destinations>
      <amq:queue physicalName="......"/>
      <amq:queue physicalName="......"/>
      <amq:queue physicalName="......"/>
      <amq:queue physicalName="......"/>
      <amq:queue physicalName="......"/>
      <amq:queue physicalName="......"/>
      <amq:queue physicalName="......"/>
    </amq:destinations>
    <amq:destinationPolicy>
      <amq:policyMap>
        <amq:policyEntries>
          <amq:policyEntry queue="......" producerFlowControl="false"/>
          <amq:policyEntry queue="......" producerFlowControl="false"/>
          <amq:policyEntry queue="......" producerFlowControl="false"/>
          <amq:policyEntry queue="......" producerFlowControl="false"/>
          <amq:policyEntry queue="......" producerFlowControl="false"/>
          <amq:policyEntry queue="......" producerFlowControl="false"/>
          <amq:policyEntry queue="......" producerFlowControl="false"/>
        </amq:policyEntries>
      </amq:policyMap>
    </amq:destinationPolicy>
<!--    <amq:systemUsage>-->
<!--      <amq:systemUsage>-->
<!--        <amq:memoryUsage>-->
<!--          <amq:memoryUsage limit="${.......limit}"/>-->
<!--        </amq:memoryUsage>-->
<!--        <amq:storeUsage>-->
<!--          <amq:storeUsage limit="${.......limit}"/>-->
<!--        </amq:storeUsage>-->
<!--        <amq:tempUsage>-->
<!--          <amq:tempUsage limit="${.......limit}"/>-->
<!--        </amq:tempUsage>-->
<!--      </amq:systemUsage>-->
<!--    </amq:systemUsage>-->
  </amq:broker>
  <!--   create a Camel ActiveMQ component to use, using the Spring bean style -->
  <!--   we use the vm protocol to communicate intra-jvm which is much faster than tcp -->
  <bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
    <!-- vm://myBroker is the vm protocol, and myBroker is the broker name -->
    <property name="brokerURL" value="vm://......-broker?broker.persistent=true"/>
  </bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveMQ will default values if you do not specify them. For store usage, that value is 100GB.

ActiveMQ needs system usage values set. It is the core job of the broker to manage computer resources (memory, disk, etc) to preserve quality of service for message delivery.

Note for readers from the future: Radovan (OP) mentioned ActiveMQ 5.19.x. At this time that version does not exist, so the version in use is unknown.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. The version of the ActiveMQ 5.19.5 is bundled in Camel 2.25.0 . Do you please know where I could find mentioned defaults?

Comment: Sorry the version of ActiveMQ is 5.15.9 indeed.

Comment: I found the following default configuration in source codes. I'm not sure when it is used though.
`<systemUsage>
            <systemUsage>
                <memoryUsage>
                    <memoryUsage percentOfJvmHeap="70" />
                </memoryUsage>
                <storeUsage>
                    <storeUsage limit="100 gb"/>
                </storeUsage>
                <tempUsage>
                    <tempUsage limit="50 gb"/>
                </tempUsage>
            </systemUsage>
        </systemUsage>`